# Why all mailboxes are receiving email in Dynamics CRM 365 (on-prem)?

Tags: email, dynamics-crm, exchange-server

We have Dynamics CRM 365 (on-prem) and Exchange Server online. We have configured Email Server Profile in CRM for Exchange Server to send/receive emails. Now, in CRM, we have around 90 active users with their mailboxes are associated with the Email Server profile for incoming and outgoing emails. All the users are allowed to send emails, and we have enabled only one mailbox to receive email. Once the email is received in CRM, the **To** field is addressing to all 90 mailboxes. And once anyone went to **Reply** or **Reply All** all users are being shown in the previous list.

I want the email should be received in CRM and all users should have access to view email and then they should allow to reply as well.